# Virtual TListView Item->SubItems->Assign() during OnData triggers refresh and hence never ending updates

Tags: c++builder, vcl

Maintaining an older project using c++ Builder 2009

In a `TListView` instance (`ViewStyle = vsReport`), setup to operate virtual (`OwnerData = true`) I wanted to try and improve speed as much as possible.  Every tiny bit helps.  In the `OnData` event I noticed that `Item->SubItems->Capacity` = 0 to start with, and it increases per 4 as sub items are added.  I read in the docs that `Capacity` is read only, yet I want to avoid `TStrings`' internal  reallocating as much as possible.  Since I also need to do caching I figured I'd use a `TStringList` as cache that has already grown to the required capacity.  I *assume* `TStrings` `Assign()` will then immediately allocate an array big enough to store the required amount of Strings in ?

```
Item->SubItems->Assign(Cache.SubItems) ;
```

While this works I noticed this triggers ListView to call OnData again, and again and ... causing it to never stop.

Easily fixed again by doing this:

```
for (int x = 0 ; x < Cache.SubItems->Count ; x++)
    Item->SubItems->Add(Cache.SubItems->Strings[x]) ;
```

But of course the whole point was to be able to tell `SubItems` the amount of strings from the start.

I realize I may be running against an old VCL issue ?  That has long been resolved ?  Or is there a point to this behavior that I don't understand right now ?

Is there a way to 'enable' `Capacity` to accept input ?  So that it allocates just enough space for the strings that will be added ?

Comment: I don't have access to any C++ Builder right now, but isn't there a `BeginUpdate();` and `EndUpdate();` that could be used to disable triggering the events while you update? Something like `obj->BeginUpdate(); ...; Item->SubItems->Assign(Cache.SubItems); ...; obj->EndUpdate();`. If not, perhaps storing the `OnData` event handler in a variable and setting it to `NULL` before `Assign()` and then setting it back after you've updated everything could work.

Comment: Excellent suggestion Ted, but it doesn't help,  Perhaps I need to rewrite my question a bit because `OnData` is not called during the `Assign()`. `OnData` completes like it normally does, it is called for all objects displayed, but the sequence for all objects starts again afterwards, and again and again.  Normally it stops when there is no activity, now it just never stops

Comment: Doing more tests it appears that when I set `Capacity`, the value sticks (when I read it out again).  The docs say it doesn't but I didn't think of the fact that the `TListViewItem` `SubItems` implementation is a class that inherits from `TStrings`

Comment: It's been awhile since I worked with `TListView` in virtual mode, but I've never had a problem with it like you have described. I have the VCL source code from CB2009, so I'll review it tomorrow and post an answer. But in the meantime, the CB2009 documentation says `TStrings::Capacity` is read/write, maybe you are confusing it with `TStrings::Count`, which is read-only? `TStrings::Assign()` calls `(Begin|End)Update()` internally. And IIRC, `TStrings::Assign()` just runs an `Add()` loop.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  I got it from here: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Capacity where it says "Read Capacity to determine the currently allocated size of the string list. For the TStrings object, reading Capacity returns the Count property, and setting Capacity does nothing."  I just now discovered `TStrings` is mostly virtual (no actual content) so then that makes sense and I suppose `TListViewItem` implements a valid Capacity ?

Comment: @Peter that doc is correct for the base `TStrings` class itself, even in CB2009.  However, the `TListItem.SubItems` property is a `TSubItems` object, which derives from `TStringList`, so `Capacity` read/write is implemented as expected.

Comment: @Peter I have added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TListView::OnData` event is triggered whenever the ListView needs data for a given list item, such as (but not limited to) drawing operations.

Note that when the `OnData` event is triggered, the `TListItem::SubItems` has already been `Clear()`'ed beforehand. `TStringList::Clear()` sets the `Capacity` to 0, freeing its current `string` array.  That is why the `Count` and `Capacity` are always 0 when entering your `OnData` handler.

The `SubItems` property is implemented as a `TSubItems` object, which derives from `TStringList`.  The `TStrings::Capacity` property setter is implemented in `TStringList`, and does what you expect to pre-allocate the `string` array.  But that is all it does - allocate VCL memory for the array, nothing more.  There is still the aspect of updating the ListView subitems themselves at the Win32 API layer, and that has to be done individually as each `string` is added to the `SubItems`.

When your `OnData` handler calls `SubItems->Assign()`, you are calling `TStrings::Assign()` (as `TStringList` and `TSubItems` do not override it). However, `TStrings::Assign()` *DOES NOT* pre-allocate the `string` array to the size of the source `TStrings` object, as one would expect (at least, not in CB2009, I don't know if modern versions do or not). Internally, `Assign()` merely calls `Clear()` and then `TStrings::AddStrings()` (which neither `TStringList` nor `TSubItems` override to pre-allocate the array).  `AddStrings()` merely calls `TStrings::AddObject()` in a loop (which both `TStringList` and `TSubItems` do override).

All of that clearing and adding logic is wrapped in a pair of `TStrings::(Begin|End)Update()` calls.  This is important to note, because `TSubItems` reacts to the update counter. When the counter falls to 0, `TSubItems` triggers `TListView` to make some internal updates, which includes calling `Invalidate()` on itself, which triggers a whole repaint, and thus triggering a new series of `OnData` events for list items that need re-drawing.

On the other hand, when you call `SubItems->Add()` in your own manual loop, and omit the `(Begin|End)Update()` calls, you are skipping the repaint of the whole ListView.  `TSubItems` overrides `TStrings::Add/Object()` to (among other things) update only the specific ListView item that it is linked to. It does not repaint the whole ListView.

So, you should be able to set the `Capacity` before entering your manual loop, if you really want to:

```cpp
Item->SubItems->Capacity = Cache.SubItems->Count;
for (int x = 0; x < Cache.SubItems->Count; ++x)
    Item->SubItems->Add(Cache.SubItems->Strings[x]);
```

In which case, you can use `AddStrings()` instead of a manual loop:

```cpp
Item->SubItems->Capacity = Cache.SubItems->Count;
Item->SubItems->AddStrings(Cache.SubItems);
```

Comment: AHA .. "TSubItems reacts to the update counter. When the counter falls to 0, TSubItems triggers TListView to make some internal updates, which includes calling Invalidate() on itself" explains it all, thanks